# How to show default image if profile image is not set in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I need to set a default image from my local file if profile pic is not set by user and how to set hover to it if the user moves the mouse close to the profile pic field to set the image.

**My HTML :**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 vheight1">
                    <h4>Profile Picture</h4>
                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" onclick='$("#my_profile_pic").click();'>
                        <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail"   data-provides="fileinput" data-trigger="fileinput" id="profile_pic">
                            <img ng-if="source" class="thumb" ng-src="{{source}}"/>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xs">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <span>
                                <span class="fileinput-new" ng-show="!hasFile()">Select image</span>
                                <span class="fileinput-new" ng-show="hasFile()">Change</span>
                            </span>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger fileinput-new glyphicon glyphicon-trash"  data-dismiss="fileinput" ng-show="hasFile()" ng-click="removefile( json, file )" ></a>
                        </div> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="file" class="hidden hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xs" id='my_profile_pic' file-model="photo">
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<img ng-if="source" class="thumb" ng-src="{{source}}"/>
```

with:

```
 <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{source ? source : 'pathtodefault.png'}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete [Piyush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38074966/4927984), you can also do:

```
<img class="thumb" ng-show="source" ng-src="{{source}}"/>
<img class="thumb" ng-show="!source" src="defaultSrc"/>
```

Comment: Its not showing anything its just shows the same white background. Did i need to use nav bar to highlight selection.

Comment: It's weird that it does not work. Can you provide me a Plunker so I could help you more?